# Pandas .drop is not removing data rom original DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code in which I need to make some iteractions with my data. The problem is when I try to remove the unecessary data: the program creates maintains the DataFrame called `a` and creates a new one with some bugs called `a[0]`.

```
a = pd.DataFrame( [0.0,]*n )

while avg(a[0]) < 0.999:

average = avg(a[0])

for i in range(1, N + 1):
    data = np.genfromtxt(str(i) + ".dat")
    y = data[:,1] 
    a[0][i] = np.vdot(y,y_avg)/(norma(y)*norma(y_avg))


a[0].drop( a[0].index[a[0] < avg(a[0])], inplace = True)
```

When I say bugs, I mean that my code here does not work all the time. If i try to put `while avg(a[0]) < 0.9999:`, for example, it simply gets in a loop forever.

I dunno what is going on. Thanks for the any help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `a[0]` returns a *new `Series`*, and then you `.drop` from that `Series` in-place, then immediately discard the `Series`:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame( [0.0,]*10 )
>>> type(a)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> type(a[0])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Since you only seem to have one column, try to use:

```
a.drop( a.index[a[0] < avg(a[0])], inplace = True)
```